# Rendering each collection item asynchronously in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am trying to render a collection of items. Normally what I would do is something like this:

```
StuffView = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  render: function(){
    ...
    this.$el.html( ... );
    return this;
  }
  ...
});

StuffCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  render: function(){
    this.collection.each(addOne, this);
  },
  addOne: function(stuff){
    var view = new StuffView({model: stuff});
    this.$el.append(view.render().el);
  }
  ...
});
```

However, this time I'm building a bit different type of view. Each StuffView's rendering takes some time, so I can't do this synchronously. The code for the new StuffView looks something like this:

```
StuffView = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  render: function(){
    ...
    // Asynchronous rendering
    SlowRenderingFunction(function(renderedResult){
      this.$el.html(renderedResult);
    });
  }
});
```

In this case, I can't just return **this** from render and append its result to the StuffCollectionView's el. One hack I thought of was to pass a callback function to StuffView's render, and let it callback when it has finished rendering. Here's an example:

```
StuffView = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  render: function(callback){
    ...
    // Asynchronous rendering
    SlowRenderingFunction(function(renderedResult){
      this.$el.html(renderedResult);
      callback(this);
    });
  }
});


StuffCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, "onStuffFinishedRendering");
  },
  render: function(){
    this.collection.each(addOne, this);
  },
  addOne: function(stuff){
    var view = new StuffView({model: stuff});
    view.render(onStuffFinishedRendering);
  },
  onStuffFinishedRendering: function(renderedResult){
    this.$el.append(renderedResult.el);
  }
  ...
});
```

But it's not working for some reason. Furthermore, this feels too hacky and doesn't feel right. Is there a conventional way to render children views asynchronously?

Comment: Pass this.addOne in render of StuffCollectionView and inside addOne do view.render(this.onStuffFinishedRendering). I think this will work. But I agree this is not best way :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you pass StuffCollectionView's el *into* the SlowRenderingFunction? It's a bit nasty but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Edit: I should say, and make SlowRenderingFunction an actual property of StuffView, so that StuffViewCollection can call it instead of calling render.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using _.defer to prevent the collection items rendering blocking the UI.

Refer http://underscorejs.org/#defer for more details.

```
StuffCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  render: function(){
    var self = this;
    _(function() {
      self.collection.each(addOne, self);
    }).defer();
  }
  ...
});
```